# An error occurred while requesting the visualization manifest

Tags: looker-studio

I am following https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-visualization#8 steps to create my visualization with manifest resources

```
"resource": {
      "js": "gs://community-viz-docs-123/myViz.js",
      "config": "gs://community-viz-docs-123/myViz.json",
      "css": "gs://community-viz-docs-123/myViz.css"
    }
```

but I am having "An error occurred while requesting the visualization manifest" error when I add path of manifest in data studio community visualization.
[As shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORfht.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please enter in Data Studio for the manifest path:

```
gs://community-viz-docs-123/myviz/
```

[image]